# Binding RadioButtonList to List<T> and setting DataValueField Proprty

Tags: c#, data-binding, asp.net-4.0

I have a class called "Answer" includes:

```
int ID;

String Text;
```

And I have a list of them like this:

```
List<Answer> myList;
```

in the web page, I have RadioButtonList that I want to bind data from the list above, so I've done:

```
AnswersButtonList.DataSource = myList;
AnswersButtonList.DataTextField = "Text";
AnswersButtonList.DataValueField = "ID";
AnswersButtonList.DataBind();
```

but the DataValueField didn't bind well! I feel I'm doing that in a wrong way, waiting your help :)

Comment: Is the class you posted "Answer" or "Question"? I think it's mis-labelled somewhere :)

Comment: Sorry, the mis-label is just here, sorry again!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try changing your ID property to string.

according to documentation here DataValueField is a string property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx

Comment: Thanks dear, but sorry it didn't work!
I've changed the ID property from int to string, but nothing happened well!

Comment: and you verified that the ID property on your collection gets populated ?

Comment: and you're checking the page source to see if values were not populated?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

Answer class has following properties

```
public string AnswerID
{
    get { return theAnswerID; }
    set { theAnswerID = value; }
}

public string Text
{
    get { return theText; }
    set { theText = value; }
}
```

then create your list and bind. If it still isn't working then I'd bind to a gridview to see what is getting churned out by your list.